# Is a function surjective if its range is $\mathbb{C}$ but the function is defined for $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

Question: Decide if the following binary relation is a function. If it is, decide if it is injective, surjective, or bijective.

$$f = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R_0^+} | 2y = \sqrt{x} \}\subset \mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R_0^+}$$

The range of $y$ here can be not just $\mathbb{R_0^+}$ but $\mathbb{C}$ if $x$ is a negative number. That is $rng(f) = \mathbb{C} \neq \mathbb{R_0^+}$. (But $\mathbb{R_0^+} \in \mathbb{C} $ though)  Does this mean the relation is not surjective?

Comment: First, decide whether $f$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_0^+$. Is $f$ a function?

Comment: This is the set of solutions to $y = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$, for $y \in \mathbb{R}^+_0$.  It eliminates the possibility of complex numbers.

Comment: @J126 Ah yeah yeah. I think I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkSaving It is a function, right..? For a fixed x there is only one possibility of y.

Comment: The fact that there is only one possibility for $y$ is because you specify that $y \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$.

Comment: @SixTwelfthsPi then what $y$ is there such that $(-1, y) \in f$?

Comment: What is the **precise** definition of a function? Do you distinguish between functions and partial functions?

Comment: $f$ is **defined** as the set of all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R_0^+}$ satisfying some condition. Thus the question whether we should have $y \in \mathbb C$ does not arise.

Comment: @MarkSaving Yeah I see the problem now. $(-1,y)$ is not in f in the first place so there isn't a $y$ in complex and the range of y is covered which is surjective.. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulFrost I was indeed struggled with definitions and now it is clear for me.. Thanks a lot for the answer